# using yesod without Shakespeare

Tags: haskell, yesod, blaze-html

[This](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/10/yesod-pure) post shows how to use yesod directly with blaze-html,but following this post ghc complains that:

```
No instance for (ToWidget App (t0 -> H.Html))
  arising from a use of ‘toWidget’
In the expression: toWidget
In a stmt of a 'do' block: toWidget $ \ render -> do { H.p "" }
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘do { toWidget $ \ render -> do { ... } }’
```

I checked source of the required [yesod.pure](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-pure-0.1.0.2/src/Yesod/Pure.hs) module,but found there's no such instance for Towidget..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you including the package `yesod-core` and the module `Yesod.Core`?

That's where the `ToWidget` class is defined.

I used [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=ToWidget) to find where `ToWidget` was defined.